# Why is sort the only event firing for jQuery UI .sortable()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a simple code example @ http://jsbin.com/ukiwo3/edit

It has 2 connected lists and a load of bound events. I'm hopeful I've missed something simple as based on http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/ Events I think I should see all these events fired when I drag and reorder a question li. At the moment only sort logs to the console.

Can anyone tell me whats wrong and how to get the rest to fire?

Thanks,
Denis

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#events - Check out the bind examples here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The events are named differently when binding, for example `sortstart` instead of `start`.  [Look at the list of events on the demo page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-sort) for a full list of what your binds should be.

Overall, [it should look like this](http://jsbin.com/ukiwo3/3):

```
$( ".questions" ).bind( "sortstop", function(event, ui) {
  console.log("stop event");
});
$( ".questions" ).bind( "sortstart", function(event, ui) {
  console.log("start event");
});
$( ".questions" ).bind( "sortchange", function(event, ui) {
  console.log("change event");
});
$( ".questions" ).bind( "sort", function(event, ui) {
  console.log("sort event");
});
$( ".questions" ).bind( "sortremove", function(event, ui) {
  console.log("remove event");
});
$( ".questions" ).bind( "sortout", function(event, ui) {
  console.log("out event");
});
$( ".questions" ).bind( "sortover", function(event, ui) {
  console.log("over event");
});
$( ".questions" ).bind( "sortupdate", function(event, ui) {
  console.log("update event");
});
```

(not optimized, just showing event names)

Comment: I knew I just needed a second pair of eyes! Should have spotted it myself. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I did this and I see the stop event get triggered:

```
$('.questions').sortable({ 
        axis: 'y', 
        connectWith: ".questions",
        placeholder: "question-highlight",
        stop:function(event, ui) {
         console.log("stop event");
        }
});
```

It seems to me those 'events' are not accessible via `bind`.