# Jquery Sortable Events Not Firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm sorry if this is super simple but I just cannot see what is wrong but the update event (or any event I have tried) is not firing in sortable. I tried to create a simple test using just the basic example they provide but it still fails. Can anyone help?

HTML:

```
<ol class='example'>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ol>
```

My main.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("ol.example").sortable({
    update:function(event, ui){
        alert("in the update");
    }
});
```

})

The closest open issue I found was [Why is sort the only event firing for jQuery UI .sortable()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467251/why-is-sort-the-only-event-firing-for-jquery-ui-sortable). But that still isn't the helping. I have also tried using binding for the event which also failed. I am using jquery version 1.9.1 in case that matters.

Comment: Did you include the required libraries? Just jQuery isn't going to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've a problem in the include of the jQuery librairies, please try to **Replace** :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jslib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jslib/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jslib/jquery-sortable.js"></script>
```

**By :**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

If it work so verify the librairies inside jslib folder.

**Full working code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <head>

    <body>

        <ol class='example'>
          <li>First</li>
          <li>Second</li>
          <li>Third</li>
        </ol>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("ol.example").sortable({
                    update:function(event, ui){
                        alert("in the update");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I do have it. I'm sorry I did not include that information. I have the following: 

<script type="text/javascript" src="jslib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jslib/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jslib/jquery-sortable.js"></script>

The sortable does work. It just does not fire events. I also was unable to use the "enable"/"disable" as they did not work either.

Comment: ok i see, you don't have any error in your console in browser ? are you sure that the 3 librairies loaded ?

Comment: No errors in Chrome. Yes I checked to see if they are loaded. The sort part is working, so the code is also running. Just no events for some reason. I tried putting in an alert outside of the update function which fired so I do know that the alerts are not being blocked.

Comment: Yes that strange, try the full code in answer in separate file.

Comment: Yes, it must have been the libraries. The updated script code worked. Thank you!!!

Comment: I was having the same issue with sortable on a table.  I changed out the libraries as suggested above and the whole thing broke, but when I got it working with the new libraries the update function also started working.  To fix my table I had to apply the sortable to the tbody tag instead of the table tag in case anyone is interested.